# Android task: click a button, go to a layout to edit personal info. click the submit button, save and display the info

Tags: java, android

I am working on a small task for an android app. And I dont really know what are the things I need to do or things I should be careful for.

In a user's personal page, there is a button where the user can click in. Then it goes to a layout where there are two buttons "cancel" and "submit". Below them, there is a blank space where the user can edit his personal info. (Here the keyboard should automatically pop up).

After he clicks "submit", the info is saved and the app goes back to the personal page and the info he just entered will be displayed.

If a user already has some text for his info, after he clicks the edit button, the whitebox in the layout should has the info that he has previously entered. from that he can re-edit and submit again.

Any type of hints and guidelines will be greatly appreciated!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good place to use `Activity` results.  You can make the screen where the user enters the information an `Activity`, and then start it by calling `Activity.startActivityForResult()`.  Once the user is finished and clicks done, you store the result with `Activity.setResult()` and call `finish()` to close that activity.  The original `Activity` that opened that screen will then get a callback in `onActivityResult()` with the data that you set in `setResult()`.  This is a pretty common task so there should be plenty of examples around.